# Python equivalent of TCL Create_FIleHandler

Tags: python, tcl

I am looking for an equivalent of TCL Create_Filehandler API . I could not find anything useful on Google.
The problem statement I am trying to solve can be simply put as: Make 1 C++ thread write something on a C++ thread with a python interpreter embedded and waiting on the python loop. Then the thread with python interpreter gets some notification and does some processing using the string it received on its input channel. I have the current implementation in TCL which uses Create_FileHandler which provides this behavior. Looking for something similar in python.

Roughly , the Code looks like:

```
void mainpythonloop(int argc , char * argc[])
{
    Py_Initialize();
    // Register a callback so that anything written onto the stdin is passed onto that and     called . [NEED HELP HERE]
    Py_Main(argc,argv); // Main Python loop , can either serve the input on its stdin or any other thread writing to its stdin. Should not wait on anything
    Py_Finalize();

}
```

Comment: Most probably there is no equivalent in Python, but you can use the Queue built-in module to communicate between threads.

Comment: Actually queue would mean a polling like scenario. Whereas I do not want the Python thread to wait on it , rather get notified.

Comment: Memory says “look at Twisted” but I don't know if that's a current, useful suggestion as I've not seriously used Python for anything much.

Comment: @DonalFellows: Twisted is both useful and current...

Comment: Let me see if I understand; you have an embedded tcl interpreter in the same process as some C++; and you want to replace/augment it with a python interpreter doing something similar?  Do you have potentially multiple threads in this process?

Comment: Actually currently there is a C++ thread and a C++ thread with a TCL interpreter in the same process.I have the communication between them working without blocking the tcl thread by using the filehandler.Now I want to switch to using python instead of TCL. But unable to find something similar. The req is that the consumer (C++ thread with embedded python) should not wait on or poll  on some shared memory to see if it received input from the other C++ thread. need to implement a mechanism where if the C++ thread wants to communicate with python , that is done via a publish/subscribe mechanism.

Comment: Also lets call the C++ thread with python as Main thread. It opens a python shell and waits for any command issued to it. Its now the duty of other C++ threads in the system to make the main thread execute some commands which they are carrying without the main having to poll for them.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect there are several ways to accomplish what you want.  I'm assuming the c++ thread writes to some file descriptor and the python interpreter thread needs to sleep until the the file descriptor has data to be read.  Here are a few ways to do that:

### Using Tkinter and the similar call to the TCL API:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def readCallback(loop):
    print("File is readable.")

tkinter.createfilehandler(fd, tkinter.READABLE, readCallback)

root.mainloop()
```

### Using poll() or select() interfaces:

```
from select import *

p = poll()
p.register(fd, POLLIN)

while True:
    p.poll()
    print("File is readable.")
```

### Using Python >= 3.4 and asyncio:

```
import asyncio

def readCallback(loop):
    print("File is readable.")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.add_reader(fd, readCallback)
loop.run_forever()
```

You could also use the selectors module which is recommended over the select module for Python 3.4.  You could also look into twisted or a similar event loop engine.

[asyncio watch file descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#watch-file-descriptors)

[Tkinter createFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3.3/faq/gui.html#can-i-have-tk-events-handled-while-waiting-for-i-o)

Comment: Thanks!
There is a slight difference though. The python interpreter thread will not sleep . It will always be running and whenever the other C++ thread "somehow" notifies it , it will process that request also.

Comment: If you are launching the C++ producer thread and the python consumer interpreter thread from the same process, I would not use a pipe or a socket to communicate between the C++ thread and Python thread.  I like pts's suggestion of using the Queue python module which is suited for producer consumer problems like yours.  The overhead of Queue will be significantly less than a socket or pipe which doesn't make sense if your threads belong to the same process. @Kanishka Khandelwal

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be saying two contradictory things.

> ... a python interpreter embedded and waiting on the python loop.

and

> The python interpreter thread will not sleep...

For one thread to notify another waiting thread, in any sort of context, the waiting thread must be waiting **on** some sort of syncronization primitive;  a lock or a pipe or some such.

The most convenient way for two python threads to communicate in this way is with a [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html).  The python code for that might look sort of like this:

```
import Queue, threading

def worker(q):
    while True:
        task = q.get()
        frobnicate(task)
        q.task_done()

work_queue = Queue.Queue()
worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(work_queue,))
worker_thread.run()

def do_task(task):
    work_queue.put(task)
```

specifically, the `worker` will repeatedly pop items off of the work queue; blocking while it's empty.  It makes internal use of several `threading.Condition` locks to manage this behavior, in a way that's mostly transparent.  In particular, the locks are only held by producers (for unbounded queues) during the brief interval that items are being added to or removed from the queue, it's highly improbable for this to take more than a tiny fraction of a second for each `put()`/`get()`

Using all this in an embedding scenario is not too different, invoke the above code in some thread, obtain a reference to `do_task` (or just `work_queue.put`) and ultimately `PyObject_Call` it from the publishing thread.